# Add default page editor to an admin settings page

Tags: wp-editor, post-editor

Is there a way to get the standard page editor into a custom administration settings page? I have been able to add other textarea boxes with toolbars, like TinyMCE/CKEditor but not replicate the exact same edit text/html view that wordpress uses when editing pages.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, this was quite easy.

I had used:

```
$args = array("textarea_name" => "wpet_options[txt]", 'default_editor' => 'text');
wp_editor( 'xxx', "wpet_options[txt]", $args );
```

But what I really wanted was:

```
$post = get_post( 117, 'OBJECT' );
wp_editor( $post, 'editor' );
```

This page explains more: http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-using-wp_editor--wp-27136